# iPhone Development - Non documented UIProgressHUD class

Tags: cocoa-touch

I've only heard about what UIProgressHUD class do, but i cannot find the implementation of this class or any documentation. Reference to this class can be found in "The iPhone Developer's Cookbook 1st Edition" book, and other articles on the internet:

> http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?UIProgressHUD
>
> http://blogs.oreilly.com/iphone/2008/02/using-a-progress-heads-up-disp.html

... and maybe others. I just want to know if i can still use this class somehow. Does anyone has the .h and .m class files? Or is there any other class that does something what UIProgressHUD is suppose to do (open an alert like window showing progress indicator with a message).

Thanks.
Mustafa

Comment: As the class is part of UIKit (according to those pages), the .m file stays with Apple. All you would need, and all you would have access to if this were a public API (which it doesn't seem to be), is the .h file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't use private APIs. If you're lucky, Apple will approve your app, then change or remove the API in an OS update, angering your customers. If you're unlucky, Apple will reject your app.

On the Mac, you can get away with it (at least temporarily). On the iPhone, don't use private APIs, **EVER**.

Edit: And since this answer was originally written, Apple added an App Store to the Mac. Same rule applies there: If you want to distribute your app in the App Store, don't use private APIs, **EVER**.

Comment: Don't cross the streams! It would be bad.

Comment: Or one could argue that, if you are lucky, Apple will reject your app. :-)

Answer (score 24):

I've created my own "progress HUD", the MBProgressHUD. I've recently published the code on my blog. If you want, you can check it out and see if it meets your needs.

You can find the code at: http://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD

Comment: Great! I'm collecting such reusable components on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843167/is-there-a-gallery-of-reusable-iphone-components-on-the-web — I'll repost you link there in a day if you don't do it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

I think UIProgressView is what you're supposed to use now.

http://www.iphonedevcentral.org/tutorials.php?page=ViewTutorial&id=43&uid=34167348

[How to integrate NSURLConnection with UIProgressView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312796/how-to-integrate-nsurlconnection-with-uiprogressview)

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, the only alternative is to roll your own, or find someone else who has done the same and is willing to share their code with you.