# How to disable iphone UI?

Tags: iphone, multithreading, uikit, user-interface

I start doing some things on multiple threads and I want to disable the UI while the new thread is working so that the user doesn't accidentally launch a duplicate. Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enable/disable controls using the `enable` property but what you really want is transparent overlay and a "Processing" message. That's answered here: [How to display a progress indicator overlay/HUD on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593147/how-to-display-a-progress-indicator-overlay-hud-on-iphone)?

Answer (score 1):

you can show a modal view