# How do I get a pop-up to display on my iphone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, popupwindow

I would like to know how to display a pop-up with some text, in an iphone application that I am developing. The part of the app I am talking about consists of some text pulled in from a plist file, all this happens in a view controller object which also consists of a button. When the user presses the button, I would like to show a pop-up window (not a small alert like the one obtained using UIAlertView but one similar to the pop-up ads that appear when you launch certain apps on the iphone, with the background dim and a window with a close button etc etc..), ya so anyway I would like to know how to achieve this, mainly if there is any pre-defined class that can make this happen. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3737911/937822.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`MBProgressHUD`](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) for this. You can add custom views in it and it also has the `dimBackground` property to dim the containing view and many other useful things.