# Bubble Notification over a Button inside the App in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, notifications

I want to know how to get Badge notification in ios. I mean inside the app. I can't post the image. Follow this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myunZ.jpg)
I want to get that badge notfication inside the app over a button.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: I know how to make the notification (Badgeview) Over the app icon. But, Notif. over a button inside the app?? No idea..!

Comment: This may help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737911/how-to-display-temporary-popup-message-on-iphone-ipad-ios

Comment: Try this - https://github.com/JaviSoto/JSBadgeView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what do you mean by "bubble notification" but maybe you meant to badge over a UIButton? maybe [CustomBadge](https://github.com/ckteebe/CustomBadge) could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but take a look at [CMPopTipView](https://github.com/chrismiles/CMPopTipView)!