# Cuperino style toast in Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, toast, snackbar

There is a lot of [Cupertino style widgets](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/cupertino) in Flutter.

I want to show short messages (like material design's snackbar).

How looks snackbar / toast in iOS and how can I show it?

Comment: There isnt a snackbar / toast in swift / objective c, this is because there isnt a snackbar / toast Cupertino style widgets. but you can use snackbar and it look fine in iOS like in androids devices.

Comment: What do they use show short messages like "Added to cart" in iOS?

Comment: Some people use UIAlertController, some build a toast like. How you can see here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737911/how-to-display-temporary-popup-message-on-iphone-ipad-ios