# How to Implement a Cool Alert/Information Overlay on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios

I understand how to include a standard alert within my iPhone application, and can dismiss it with an OK or CLOSE button (see Epicurious example in image).

How can I make a cool alert/notice overlay like the one seen in the foursquare app (see foursquare example in image)? In particular, how to include the alert/notice layout with graphic. Is this a separate view?

If you can point me to a tutorial or sample code that will get me moving in the right direction, it's *much* appreciated! :)

[image]

Comment: I would say that Foursquare uses a custom UIImageView, or with not this: http://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD

Answer (score 1):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593147/how-to-display-a-progress-indicator-overlay-hud-on-iphone).

Answer (score 1):

Jeff Lamarche has a nice write up on the topic [here](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/02/implementing-wait.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sam Vermette has a nice blog post about this http://samvermette.com/309

And [this is his corresponding github project](https://github.com/samvermette/SVStatusHUD).

It's as easy as this:

```
[SVStatusHUD showWithImage:image status:@"Hello World!" duration:3];
```