# Overlaying view with remove button

Tags: ios, xcode, view, overlay

I have searched high and low, and maybe because of not defining the problem correctly, I can't seem to figure out how to achieve the following: [image: http://andrewho.nl/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Photo-30-03-13-09-55-06.png]

I want to add a overlaying transparent view with a remove button. Any thoughts or tutorials I can use?

I have looked at the following but I want to have it fullscreen with a remove button:
[How to Implement a Cool Alert/Information Overlay on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738504/how-to-implement-a-cool-alert-information-overlay-on-iphone)

Comment: have you try loading a semitransparent costume modal view on top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a new `UIView` (let's call it OverlayView) in interface builder, with the size of the main view, and above the others, with `clearColor` background color. Inside that `UIView` put an `UIImageView` with the overlay image (it has to be a semi transparent png) and `UIButton` for closing (on tap remove the OverlayView from superview)

Comment: Thanks, it was easier then i thought it would be :)