# iPhone HUD screen

Tags: ios4

When the user clicks a UIButton, I want a HUD-like Window saying "loading" for a few seconds (maybe 5 seconds). Although my application doesn't need a loading screen (between views).

Comment: i want to learn how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never make the user wait for nothing. 5 seconds is an eternity.

In the interest of education and assuming you will one day need to show a loading indicator this blog may have some info you need.

http://iphonedevcentral.blogspot.com/2010/08/showing-loading-message-over-iphone.html

Comment: I would then advise you to rephrase the question, maybe indicate that something will take a certain amount of time and that you would like to show a loading indicator to users during that time.

Answer (score 0):

I've just added an example using a one of my github project here to display / hide a HUD with an activity indicator :

[How to display a progress indicator overlay/HUD on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593147/how-to-display-a-progress-indicator-overlay-hud-on-iphone/7442094#7442094)