# Is there a gallery of reusable iPhone components on the web?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

There are quite a few reusable iPhone solutions/tricks on the web, mostly scattered on various blogs. However I could not find any single place where they would be collected together (something like what MacUpdate/VersionTracker is to applications).

Is there such a site already?

If not, I'm thinking to create one. What components would you like to see there, and what features do you think such a site needs? (I'm thinking about sharing non-visual classes as well as visual components, and maybe simple code snippets showing various techniques/tricks too.)

I'm aware of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640805/open-source-iphone-components-reusable-views-controllers-buttons-table-cells.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think all the answers are missing a point here.

Here are the sites from were you can find reusable components.

1) http://cocoacontrols.com/

2) http://open.iphonedev.com/

3) http://cocoaobjects.com/

Here is the twitter account where you can find popular reusable components on github about iPhone or iPad

4) https://twitter.com/#!/github_objc

Comment: Would upvote twice if I could. Marked this as a real answer, finally!

Answer (score 8):

If you need to display some sort of activity indication while doing background tasks, you can take a look at [MBProgressHUD for iPhone](http://www.bukovinski.com/2009/04/08/mbprogresshud-for-iphone/).

Answer (score 5):

The [Three20](http://joehewitt.com/post/the-three20-project/) "library" helped me a lot with understanding how to create reusable components.

Perhaps you already know what functionality to implement. Plus, the library itself is already quite extensive.

Comment: Yes, it's great. Unfortunately it kinda suffers from a “not invented here” syndrome, subclassing and extending the world. But it's a really good source of example code nevertheless. (Just *please* don't create reusable components that way. Self-contained Component.h/Component.m rules!)

Comment: @Andrey: Could you explain a bit more about your last line?

Comment: @Kriem: almost any class in Three20 brings a few other classes with it, so that you need to pull the whole library to use a component. If you want to create a component that's truly reusable and not a pain in the ass, your best choice is to constrain yourself to a single .h and a single .m file that can be added to any iPhone project. This also means your components should not rely on any custom utility categories on standard classes.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for an iPhone UI for web page design, check out the free [IUI on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/iui/).

Answer (score 3):

[Great iPhone custom UI elements repository](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/tree/master)

Comment: I think you need to mention it's Three20 in the body of the post — there is one other reply about it.

Answer (score 3):

Graph component. Sweet and simple to use. Straighforward iPhone way: http://code.google.com/p/s7graphview/

Comment: A cool component indeed, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Kal implements a Calendar like the one in the Calendar app for you.
http://github.com/klazuka/Kal