# Open-source frameworks/projects for iPhone platform

Tags: iphone, open-source, frameworks

I'm looking for a collection of open-source frameworks/projects for the iPhone platform.

I've found quite a few good frameworks and resources. Such as [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), [DrawKit](http://apptree.net/drawkit.htm), and [Cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) just to name a few.

I'm just curious about the minor, or unknown frameworks that have yet surfaced or that I'm unaware of. Do any of you know of frameworks that are not mentioned in the following [link](http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/resources/open-source)?

Some of the frameworks that I've found and utilize in some of my iPhone applications can be found here ([list of iPhone frameworks](http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/resources/open-source)).

I'm not limiting the scope or type of frameworks/projects all are welcome.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905407/useful-iphone-libraries

Comment: @ notnoop, 
I'm aware of these other SO questions. I've gleaned alot of information from them. The particular question that I asked is about unknown frameworks/projects that are not on the beaten path or are really not known.

Comment: DrawKit is not an iOS framework

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a pretty cool library:

"ASIHTTPRequest is an easy to use wrapper around the CFNetwork API that makes some of the more tedious aspects of communicating with web servers easier. It is written in Objective-C and works in both Mac OS X and iPhone applications."
- http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Also, here's a list I stumbled upon in my travels:

- http://code.google.com/p/iui/ (UI library for Safari iPhone apps)
- http://iwebkit.net/ (another UI library for Safari)
- http://code.google.com/p/oolongengine/ (Google engine for iPhone)
- http://www.smartfoxserver.com/labs/API/ (SmartFoxServer multiplayer engine details for their new iPhone/iPod Touch API)
- http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/ (Objective-C based 2D engine for the iPhone)
- http://www.unity3d.com (3D engine for iPhone and other platforms)
- http://blogs.unity3d.com/
- http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/12/updated-opengl-es-xcode-project.html (OpenGL template for Xcode)
- http://www.garagegames.com/products/consoles (2d and 3d engines for iPhone)
- http://www.garagegames.com/products/torque-2d/iphone
- http://www.stonetrip.com/ (3d development tool)
- http://code.google.com/p/cocoahttpserver
- http://sio2interactive.com/HOME/HOME.html (free open source 3D engine for iPhone)
- http://homepage.mac.com/aglee/downloads/appkido.html (great alternative for the class/library browser)
- http://code.google.com/p/simple-iphone-image-processing/
- http://code.google.com/p/appsales-mobile/ (locally built app for gathering metrics on your app)
- http://ioquake3.org/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id_Tech_3
- http://unifycommunity.com/ (community for Unity3d development)
- http://www.fmod.org/index.php/products/fmodex (music/audio engine)
- http://code.google.com/p/simple-iphone-image-processing/
- http://groups.google.com/group/cocos2d-iphone-discuss
- http://monoclestudios.com/cocos2d_whitepaper.html
- http://www.neverreadpassively.com/2009/03/review-of-iphone-3d-engines.html
- http://code.google.com/p/bullet/ (physics engine)
- http://www.box2d.org/ (physics engine)
- http://digitalbreed.com/2008/3d-engines-on-iphone-ipod
- http://wiki.slembcke.net/main/published/Chipmunk (physics engine)

Comment: Yes, ASIHTTPRequest is a cool little library to have in your bag of frameworks/projects.

Answer (score 3):

The following questions list many good iPhone open source frameworks:

- [What open source Cocoa/Cocoa Touch Frameworks are out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501981/what-open-source-cocoa-cocoa-touch-frameworks-are-out-there)
- [Open source iPhone components? Reusable views, controllers, buttons, table cells, etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640805/open-source-iphone-components-reusable-views-controllers-buttons-table-cells)
- [Is there any open source OCR project for the iPhone out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964181/is-there-any-open-source-ocr-project-for-the-iphone-out-there)
- [Is there a good charting library for iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769749/is-there-a-good-charting-library-for-iphone)
- [Open Source Cocoa/Cocoa-Touch POP3/SMTP library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740939/open-source-cocoa-cocoa-touch-pop3-smtp-library)
- [Open source iPhone Coverflow like library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718984/open-source-iphone-coverflow-like-library)
- [Open Source VoIP/SIP Objective-C Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493050/open-source-voip-sip-objective-c-code)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.ohloh.net/p?query=iphone

Answer (score 2):

instead of listing open source components.

Here are the sites from were you can find reusable components

1) http://cocoacontrols.com/

2) http://open.iphonedev.com/

3) http://cocoaobjects.com/

Here is the twitter account where you can find popular reusable components on github about iPhone or iPad
4) https://twitter.com/#!/github_objc

as answered here [Is there a gallery of reusable iPhone components on the web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843167/is-there-a-gallery-of-reusable-iphone-components-on-the-web/6891857#6891857)