# Some open source libraries,UI components , Frameworks, Reusable views, controllers, buttons, table cells, etc?

Tags: iphone, ios4

Some of the open source libraries which can be reused.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640805/open-source-ios-components-reusable-views-controllers-buttons-table-cells-et

Comment: The above is the link to find some of those....

Comment: @Empty stack,I kept this for my future reference,and some one also searching by other keywords can easily find and can get help.

Comment: Other link to go with the answer is....

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953550/open-source-frameworks-projects-for-iphone-platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three20 is the best open source project which implements the custom UI components. MailCore is a project which implements the framework for doing stuff with IMAP, pop and other mail related  protocol.

Comment: Thanks buddy,well i do know that why i have posted the link in my comment as well.
Thanks for putting your effort to answer..I have kept that question for future reference and anybody looking for the same...