# Disabled touch when UIProgressBarHUD is shown

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiprogressbar

I've created an app where I'm creating a UIProgressBarHUD to show that something is loading. My question is, how can I disable the view so nothing can be pressed untill the loading is finished?

I've tried setting:

```
[self.view setUserInterationEnabled:NO];
```

However this doesn't work :/

Here is the code I'm using for adding the UIProgressHUD:

```
- (IBAction) showHUD:(id)sender
{
       //[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

       UIProgressHUD *HUD = [[UIProgressHUD alloc]
initWithWindow:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];
       [HUD setText:@"Loading…"];
       [HUD show:YES];

       [HUD performSelector:@selector(done) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.5];
       [HUD performSelector:@selector(setText:) withObject:@"Done!"
afterDelay:1.5];
       [HUD performSelector:@selector(hide) withObject:nil afterDelay:4.0];

       //[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

       [HUD release];
}
```

Any help would be muchly appreciated!!
- James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416015/iphone-development-non-documented-uiprogresshud-class), UIProgressHUD is private. You should not use it.

There is a [library](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) that gives you what you are looking for though.

It allows you to keep the user from tapping anything while it is updating as you requested.

Comment: Oh right, I've always read to be careful with non documented features. Why on earth would apple have this available if you aren't allowed to use it? I'll give the MBProgressHUD a go.. Thanks

Comment: I've found that this method is good but when continuously pressing the button to show the HUD it will crash within no time :/

Comment: Have you used this code? By removing the HUD release in hudWasHidden then it no longer crashes.. hmm

Answer (score 3):

You can disable user interaction with the nifty property named `userInteractionsEnabled`, that is defined for `UIView`. It just so happens that `UIWindow` is a subclass of `UIView`, we we can easily disable user interactions for out whole app.

```
anyViewInYouApp.window.userInteractionsEnabled = NO;
```

Or keep a reference to the window if you like.

Answer (score 3):

In MBProgressHUD.m

```
#define APPDELEGATE                         
(TMAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]

- (void)show:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [[APPDELEGATE window] setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]; //use this line
}

- (void)hide:(BOOL)animated 
{  
    [[APPDELEGATE window] setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; //use this line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIWindow *win = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
[win setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```