# Framework for iPhone wait screens

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I ran across a small framework some time back that someone put together for iPhone wait screens.  But now I can't find any trace of it.  Does anyone have a link to it?  It may not be a framework as much as a few code snippets.  But the guy had it all pre-made.  You just needed to implement and specify the type of wait screen you wanted.

Comment: what was name of framework...? what was guy's name...? from where you have download it...? what it was exactly doing...? what where how when why...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you mean MBProgressHUD???

http://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Comment: Thanks but looks like that one could be trouble b/c of private APIs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416015/iphone-development-non-documented-uiprogresshud-class

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know how to get it to work with NSURLConnection and its associated delegates?  I pass it a method that contains my NSURLConnection setup.  The progress displays for the setup method but not all the way through completion of connectionDidFinishLoading.

Comment: Maybe you should use the show and hide methods instead of passing it a method. I hope this works!