# Objective-C: Get size of a PDF that loads inside a webpage from NSURLResponse

Tags: objective-c, nsurl

How can i get the size of a pdf that loads inside a webpage? Usually I use the headers from the NSURLResponse to distinguish the size, but in this case I dont know how to do. The header i get looks like:

```
response headers: {
"Cache-Control" = "max-age=3600, private, must-revalidate";
"Content-Disposition" = "inline; filename=000164702760379530.pdf";
"Content-Type" = "application/pdf; charset=UTF-8";
Date = "Sun, 16 Jan 2011 14:47:45 GMT";
Pragma = "";
Server = "AtyponWS/7.1";
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
"X-Webstats-Respid" = b0324d930da3307597086eafb0e149c5;
```

Does anyone know how to get the size of the whole page including the pdf or just the pdf?

Answer (score 0):

See this: [How to determine the size (in bytes) of a file downloading using NSURLConnection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205167/how-to-determine-the-size-in-bytes-of-a-file-downloading-using-nsurlconnection/4703291#4703291)

You can use the NSURLResponse method

```
[httpResponse expectedContentLength];
```