# progress bar when downloading image

Tags: iphone, ipad, progress-bar

How would I go about adding a progress bar for downloading a large image, or any file for that matter? here is my code:

```
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                             NSUserDomainMask, YES);

        NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *downloadPath = [[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://www.zzz.com/%@.jpg",chartFileName]autorelease];
        NSString *savePath = [[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@/%@.jpg",docsPath, chartFileName]autorelease];
        NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:downloadPath];
        NSData *downloadedChartData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        [url release];
        [downloadedChartData writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override connection:didReceiveData: in your NSURLConnection call. See here for more:

[How to integrate NSURLConnection with UIProgressView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312796/how-to-integrate-nsurlconnection-with-uiprogressviewx)

Comment: There is no explicit NSURLConnection call in "[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]", can you give a pointer to a full  download-with-progress implementation that starts with just the URLstring?

Comment: or ready solution http://www.developers-life.com/progress-bar-download-file-on-iphone.html

Answer (score 0):

Run a selector in the background that checks the image's download size, and compares it against the required size. Then set the % of the progress bar to downloaded/required.